# Find a substring in a string and return its index?

Tags: python

I have a list, for example

```
list = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'maryland college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha', 'shores of gold']
```

I want to first get all of the ones that have the letters `'ha'` in them and put them into a separate list, which I did.

Now the list looks like

```
new_list = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha']
```

Now what i want to do is count the number of letters in each phrase up until the letters `'ha'` Harvard, for example, should be 0, university of hawaii should be 14, etc.

I was not able to find a way to do this, so I was wondering if it was even possible.

Comment: The `find()` method will return the position of a substring in a string.

Comment: `harvard.find('ha')` returns `0`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you Barmar.

Comment: All I did was google "python position of substring". What did you search for when you couldn't find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the string `index` method is what you want:

```
for item in list_with_ha:
    index = item.index("ha")
    print(f'"ha" was found at index: {index}')
```

That index is also how many characters came before the `'ha'`. You can also use `find`, they both work in the same way if the string you are searching for is found (one raises an exception if not found, the other returns `-1`), and you have assured that `'ha'` is found somewhere in each string.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha']
output = list(map(lambda x: x.find('ha'), your_list)) 

# output == [0, 14, 0, 4, 5, 8]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.partition("seperator")`

```
def count_to_ha(phrase):
    return len(phrase.partition("ha")[0])
```

Usage: `count_to_ha("harvard")`

Comment: What a weirdly convoluted way to do it!

Comment: Yep, to use `find()` would be better. Just throwing another idea into the hat.

Answer (score 0):

This dictionary will print out the result clearly:

```
l = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'maryland college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha', 'shores of gold']

d = {}

for word in l:
    d[word] = len(word.split('ha')[0])

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'harvard': 0,
 'university of hawaii': 14,
 'harrisburg college': 0,
 'maryland college': 16,
 'Binghampton': 4,
 'shorehard university': 5,
 'amamamamha': 8,
 'shores of gold': 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise script if you are looking for:

```
list = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'maryland college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha', 'shores of gold']
res_list = [a.find('ha') for a in list if a.__contains__("ha")]

print(res_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 14, 0, 4, 5, 8]
```

**Explaination:**

- A string can use method `__contains__()` to check if it contains a substring.
- `find()` method returns to the first index where the substring is found
- The code above use `list comprehension` for concise. See this https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the three lists:

```
l1 = ['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'maryland college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha', 'shores of gold']
l2 = [w for w in l1 if 'ha' in w]
l3 = [len(w.split('ha')[0]) for w in l2]

print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

Output:

```
['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'maryland college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha', 'shores of gold']
['harvard', 'university of hawaii', 'harrisburg college', 'Binghampton', 'shorehard university', 'amamamamha']
[0, 14, 0, 4, 5, 8]
```

Comment: You should merge your two answers to one.

Comment: Then what's `Add another answer` for?

Comment: The two answers are not too long and not worth to separate them to 2, it should be one. If you don't think that, keep it.